# Vuejs how do i fade a div

Tags: php, mysql, css, vuejs2

I have to insert some data when I press the insert button  to the database and I want to see each row then after one 0.5 sec the div will disappeare. I know the code is wrong is just for example to understand.

```
    <?php

    $contents = file_get_contents("foo.txt.001");
    $pollfields = explode(',', $contents);

    foreach ($pollfields as $key) {

                $sql = "INSERT INTO keywords (`keys`) VALUES ('".$key."')";
                if ($conn->query($sql) === TRUE) {

 <div v-if="show" transition="fade" >
        <div class="alert alert-success" role="alert">
         <strong>$key</strong>
     </div>
    </div>
                echo ;
            } else {
                echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . $conn->error;
            }
    }

    ?>
<script> new Vue({ el: '#demo', data: { show: true } }) </script>
```

and this css:

```
.fade-enter-active, .fade-leave-active {
  transition: opacity .5s
}
.fade-enter, .fade-leave-to /* .fade-leave-active below version 2.1.8 */     {
  opacity: 0
}
```

Comment: Your code is vulnerable to [**SQL injection**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection) attacks. You should use prepared statements with bound parameters, via either the [**mysqli**](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.prepare.php) or [**PDO**](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php) drivers. [**This post**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php) has some good examples.

Comment: i know but how i fade the div lol in vue i want to apper the disapper  0.5 sec later

Comment: Where's your vue code?

Comment: <script>
   new Vue({
      el: '#demo',
      data: {
      show: true
     }
   })
   </script>

Answer (score 2):

You need to use the `animation` element like so:

```
<transition name="fade">
    <div v-if="show">
     // content to be animated
    </div>
</transition>
```

https://jsbin.com/laxoqo/edit?html,js,output

Comment: it just stand there it doesn't disapear

Comment: have you clicked the button?

Comment: Yes, I see one in the fiddle. The example was just for you to understand the basics now you must to adapt it to your needs. I put the button there just to have an easy way to trigger the animation :)

Comment: I see it now when I load it just stop now i works, thanks

Comment: It's updated. Just click the button to toggle the text

Answer (score -6):

Use jQuery, it has some great built in features for this.

```
$('#id').fadeOut()
```

ought to do the trick. You can download jquery [here](https://jquery.com/download/).

Comment: Unless the OP mentioned or tagged jQuery, it is generally best to offer a solution with the libraries mentioned (e.g. VueJS), but then after that you mention jQuery

Comment: Since the user asked only for vuejs2, you have to help him with the vuejs solution only.